# Max-width 241px not working in the smallest browser size

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have max-width:241px for 240px browser size, but this media query is not call when the browser size is 240px instead max-width:420xpx called.

How to fix this? [Link](http://www.homecredit.ph/testEnvironment/), here's the link for [Mobile emulator](http://www.studiopress.com/responsive/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width:241px){
.home-header-div{ height: 750px !important; }
}
```

instead

```
@media screen and (max-width:420px)
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `min-width`?

Comment: min-width iin 420px or 240px? if in 240px, i already did this `@media only screen and (min-width:241px)` but still it's not working in 240px browser size :(

Answer (score 0):

when the browser size is 240px then 240 will be called since you have rule defined for it. media query will take the ranges, If you have similar ranges defined then it will take the last one defined..

```
body {
    background-color:lightgreen;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color:lightblue;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 490px) {
    body {
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

In this eg color will be blue only for 10px range

Comment: i don't have similar range

Comment: Browser size at 420 it will go with 420Rule only,,

Comment: yes, i'm using mobile emulator, http://www.studiopress.com/responsive/, you can check it there. in 240px the designated media queries is not working

Comment: \\Upto 420px`@media only screen and (min-width:241px){
.home-header-div{ height: 750px !important; }
} \\above 420px    @media screen and (min-width:420px){}` This will work

Comment: can you gimme the URL or fiddle your code.. links given above shows different page

Comment: here's the mobile emulator that i'm using: http://www.studiopress.com/responsive/ and here's the site: http://www.homecredit.ph/testEnvironment/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110366/discussion-between-karthikeyan-sundaramoorthi-and-user014019).

Answer (score 0):

240 is less than both 241 and 420 so it meets the criteria for both media queries. That means that if you have the same property applied to the same element(s) in both media queries then the property applied using the selector with the highest [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) will be used. If both selectors are of equal specificity, then the cascading rules of **C**SS will kick in and the property that is declared last will be used.

Without seeing your media query for 420px, I can only assume that the latter is the cause of your issue. There are 2 solutions to this, which to use will depend on your own needs; either place the media query for 420px before the one for 241px, like so:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:420px){/* styles go here*/}
@media only screen and (max-width:241px){/* styles go here*/}
```

Or, add a `min-width` to your 420px query, like so:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:240px){/* styles go here*/}
@media only screen and (min-width:241px) and (max-width:420px){/* styles go here*/}
```

Note above how I changed the `max-width` in the first query to 240px and used 241px for the `min-width` in the second query; `max-width` means the window width must be less than *or equal to* the provided width and `min-width` means the window must be greater than or equal to the provided width. So a window of width 240px will meet match the `max-width:240px`. And, by making the `min-width` of the next media query larger by 1px, you avoid the potential for any nasty overlaps that would recreate your original problem.

Comment: i already have this `@media only screen and (max-width:420px)
@media only screen and (max-width:241px)` but 241px is not applied in 240px browser size. I will try the 2nd option

Comment: i tried your suggestion but still the 240px media queries is not working

Comment: Can you update your question with a working example of the problem, please?